# Rails 4: Image path not working in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am trying to access an image in production environment that is already uploaded to amazon s3. I am using path like this:

```
    <img src="http://my_bucket_name.s3-website-my_region.amazonaws.com/mobile.png" class="wow fadeInRight" alt="mobile">
```

But the path that is taken in production environment is as below:

```
    <img src="assets/mobile.png" class="wow fadeInRight" alt="mobile">
```

I don't know how this assets path is appearing here. However I can access this image in my development environment using the above s3-bucket path.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Post your rails code and model which is responsible to upload the images to s3

Comment: The images uploaded using carrier wave are displaying in the app properly in the development mode as well as in production mode; but the static images which are present in the assets/images, I uploaded them to  Amazon S 3 while deploying the app to elastic beanstalk. and I am trying to  access these images  via s 3 path. In development the images are loading properly with this s 3 path. But for the same s 3 path images are not rendering in production environment. Though i mentioned the s 3 path  in production, it is taking the assets path. what might be the issue i am not getting.

Comment: Please show production code, where you have specified asset_host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `asset_host` for production environment as follow:

```
# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com" # s3 bucket URL
```